# Converting UTC date/time to a local format. How would one access a field from a Dozer Convert method using Java?

Tags: java, converters, dozer

I am using the Dozer framework to copy the attributes of one class to another.

```
public class Source  {

    private BigDecimal customerid;
    private BigDecimal tenantid;
    private BigDecimal salutation;
    private String timezone;
    private Calendar createdate;
}

public class Target {

    private BigDecimal customerid;
    private String timezone;
    private String createdate;
}
```

So far, a function has been created and is working fine when executing the 2 lines below:

```
List<Source> customrlist = customerdao.findByTenantid(tenantid);

// copy the data into the structure that is to be returned to the client
List<Target> actual = DozerListServices.map(mapper, customrlist,
        Target.class);
```

Now, there is a desire to make a change.

One of the attributes being used (in the Source class) is Calendar.

The goal would be to convert "Calendar" to a "String" (in the Target class). The string would be in a certain format (ex: YYYY-MM-DD )

In order to do this, it has been suggested to use a "DozerConverter" - which would looks something like this:

```
public class DozerStringToCalTimeConvert extends
        DozerConverter<String, Calendar> { 

    public DozerStringToCalTimeConvert() {
        super(String.class, Calendar.class);
    }


    @Override
    public Calendar convertTo(String source, Calendar destination) {

        if (!StringUtils.hasLength(source)) {
            return null;
        }
        Calendar dt = null;

        return dt;
    }

    @Override
    public String convertFrom(Calendar source, String destination) {
        if (source == null) {
            return null;
        }   
        return source.toString();
    }
}
```

Although one can use Formatters to convert Calendar to the corret representation (ex: YYYY-MM-DD), the problem is that the date is in UTC format. One of the attributes in the "Source" class is "timezone". Timezone would look like 'America/Chicago', 'US/Eastern', etc. The "timezone" information is needed to convert the UTC time to a local time. With the sample Converter code above, how could one make changes to it so that one could access "timezone" from the Source class.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

The `Calendar` class is now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Most likely your `Calendar` object is actually a `GregorianCalendar`. Test with `instanceOf`. If so, cast and convert to `java.time.ZonedDateTime`.

```
if ( myCal instanceOf GregorianCalendar ) {
    GregorianCalendar gc = (GregorianCalendar) myCal ;
    ZonedDateTime zdt = gc.toZonedDateTime() ;
    LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;  // A date-only value deduced from the time zone assigned.
    String output = ld.toString() ;  // Generate string in standard ISO 8601 format YYYY-MM-DD. 
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. Above, I see that you have that I should use "ZonedDateTime". The Zone being used is not local per se but is fetched from the DB. In the "Source" class above, there is a field for the Zone called "timezone". Can this value be accessed from a class that has extended "DozerConverter" - see the converter class above called "DozerStringToCalTimeConvert". Can the attribute be accessed from the method "convertTo" or "convertFrom"? If so, how?

Comment: how can one use "instanceOf" in either method "convertTo" or "convertFrom"? TIA

Comment: @CaseyHarrils See my edit and [the Oracle.com Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) to learn about `instanceOf`. I know nothing of Dozer, so I cannot help you there.

Comment: @CaseyHarrils You do not provide enough details to help with time zone. All I can tell you is that databases handling of date-time varies *widely*. Some like Postgres store the date-time adjusted into UTC and discard original zone info. Some remember the zone and return it. At any rate, if you have a `Calendar` object then you have a zone assigned though that zone may well be UTC. Converting to `ZonedDateTime` as I showed preserves that zone assignment.